# Running youtube videos on android emulator

Tags: android, youtube, emulation

Is it possible to run youtube videos on android emulator?On other thread i got the answer that it will run on device but not on emulator.Is there a way to run youtube videos on android emulator?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can run youtube videos on emulator for that you have to use google api images in creating the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

> if you wants to run youtube videos in emulator you have to install youtube app in emulator then only the youtube api will work